# Codeigniter sessions die

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

After a little bit of use (25min - 1.5 hour) in my system, users experience a kick. For some reason my sessions are kind of dyeing. I think that the cookie on the client side somehow loses the session ID and creates  a new one. I am saving my session data on `Database`.

This is my session conf:

```
        $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'v2Session';
        $config['sess_expiration']      = 32400; //session will be 9 hours, for a shift.
        $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
        $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
        $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
        $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
        $config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
        $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
        $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Now, when I look in the DB I see multiple sessions for each user. Each kick means a new session and the old session is not deleted until it expires. When the session "detaches" the users need to login again.

Any help troubleshooting this will be appreciated.

EDIT:

So after some research I have noticed that the sessions die because the `session_id` that is saved in the `cookie` and the `session_id` that is saved in the `database` do not match. I suspect that this happens when the user loads 2 pages each on a different tab/window. One load happens just when the session updates the `session_id` and the second load (which kills the session) with the old `session_id`. The system looks for the session in the `database` and doesn't find it. **Result:** Kick from the system + mad user.

Has anybody experienced this? and does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Since you have `sess_match_ip` set to true – have you checked if their IP is still the same?

Comment: I agree with @CBroe - I would change sess_match_ip to false. I always leave it as false and I have never experienced this kind of issue. Most of your users are almost certainly going to be using dynamic IP addresses (even more so if they access it via mobile devices) so you shouldn't rely on matching the IP address.

Comment: @CBroe - I just recently changed `sess_match_ip` to try and get rid of this problem. @Matthew - This is an office application and most of my users(90%) are using static IP's.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the **CI_Session** class, or enabling logging to see if CI is intentionally starting new sessions? If it is, you can likely backtrack from there to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer.

**Do not start session at multiple instances.**, just check for existing ones, if we are talking about Authorization, then kick the user to AuthLogin page if Session does not exist.
Create a Auth class / library and let it handle things. If the session does not exist, it will ask to create another.

Those are not 'multiple' sessions, the unique Session ID is statistically random string with very strong entropy, hashed with MD5 for portability, and regenrated (by default) every five minutes)

-- [Check here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) under **How do Sessions work?**

When you perform session_destroy, it destroys sessions (multiple or single) related to the user, from database and also expires the cookie. Yes, bad design, I know!

**From your EDIT of question**

> So after some research I have noticed that the sessions die because
>   the session_id that is saved in the cookie and the session_id that is
>   saved in the database do not match. I suspect that this happens when
>   the user loads 2 pages each on a different tab/window. One load
>   happens just when the session updates the session_id and the second
>   load (which kills the session) with the old session_id. The system
>   looks for the session in the database and doesn't find it.

Opening page in multiple tabs = Refresh on single tab.

Are you setting Sessions without checking about their existence? Please share your script.

I will keep an eye on this answer until we have figured this.

Yes, I had similar issue, it turned out that I used to set sessions without checking if they already existed and everytime, I created them, they over-lapped the Session (cookie) in the browser and created another row in database. It sounds like you're facing the same issue?

**Ugly hack**

Set this as your config:

```
    $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'v2Session';
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 32400; //session will be 9 hours, for a shift.
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
    $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
    $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
    $config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 32400; // Session will update in 9 hours.
```

This is one-of-a-kind issue... However, on analyzing that sessions are mis-matching with database, it clearly indicates that upon sess_time_to_update, database might not be updating the relevant id... However, this solution would still be an assumption unless you try it.

Comment: What do you mean `Are you setting Sessions without checking about their existence? `? A session is created(if doesn't already exist) when the website is loaded and if it doesn't have a logged in flag, the user will be directed to a log-in form. On log-in I insert my relevant data into the session. To do so I simply execute: `$this->session->set_userdata($user);` and to check if I have a live session I simply do: `if(!$this->session->userdata('logged'))`. It seems very straight forward, and doesn't look like it should fail. I didn't understand what code you wanted me to share.?

Comment: Hmmm... You question is about authenticating the user and keeping it steady... Many of us have worked on CI and it works fine with all of us, which means, CI core has no issues... Thus, if there is an error, it has to be in your code, where you authenticate... Have you played around with `$this->session->all_userdata()` and checked?

Comment: Also, if you are not skeptic, I would like to see your config.php , please feel free to remove parts which are not meant to be viewed publicly.

Comment: The session part of my config.php is already posted in the question, what part are you interested in? Also the authentication presses works, I added some logging to the Session.php core to see where it dies and it always dies at `sess_read()` at the Database check `if ($query->num_rows() == 0)`. Could this be due to loading a secondary Database `$DB2 = $this->load->database($config,TRUE);`?

Comment: Ahhh, now we touch base! Yes mate... It has to do with secondary database. We can just diagnose and evaluate... How many database huge is this app?

Comment: I have a my main (contains ci_sessions) database which is always `$this->db` and I have many others (8K) which are always called like so `$DBx = $this->load->database($config,TRUE);`. I have done some testing with loading from different dbs a and from the main db and I couldn't recreate this session detach.

Comment: Wait... I guess I have misunderstood your comment, are you saying, sessions are stored in multiple databases? Please re-phrase.

Comment: My sessions are stored on 1 database, that is the database that is configured in the `database.php` file under config folder as `'default'`. The rest of my `database` connections are dynamic.

Comment: So database is configured correctly for sessions... tried disabling cache?

Comment: I never enabled caching so I'm not sure how I would disable it...
 `CI` documentation talks about enabling so I assume its not automatically enabled.

Comment: If security is not a concern, I would recommend disabling ['sess_time_to_update'] in your config... it re-generates every 5 mins for security purposes...

Comment: If you want we can move this to chat in about next 15 mins... what say?

Comment: Security is an issue, and if you have time to chat that would be great :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also an codeigniter developer. I have also applied below code in my application:-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 300; // 7200
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = true;
$config['sess_use_database']    = true;
$config['sess_table_name']      = TBL_SESSION;
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

In my application , after each 5 minute , session will expire. I am using table tbl_session for saving the record. Considering the below 2 condition , it's working perfectly for my application:-

```
1) opening application in firefox mozilla at 10:55 pm then it will take You in login screen at 11:00 pm.

2) at the same time , opening application in chrome browser at 10:56 pm  then it will take You in login screen at 11:05 pm.
```

1 thing to remember - the above code will be in your **config.php** and in each controller of Your application , there will be a checking for session activeness.

Comment: @Dvir Levy is it help You?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this:

1. Check if user has an active session IF Session is active = Nothing to do everything is fine

now if user don't have an active session, you need to do 2 things

1. get the user cookies and if there is cookies you make the session start again and the user will be fine and logged in directly with depending on cookies he have

B. if the session is not active and there is not cookies, you need to take him to login page

here is an example

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Login_USERNAME", $expire);
?>
```

In the example above the expiration time is set to a month (60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours * 30 days).

ok now you should get the cookies

```
    <?php
///Check if session alive or not
if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
     //Do Nothing the user is logged in 

    }
///There is Cookies BUT No Session
elseif (isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && empty($_SESSION['user'])){
      // Here you can see that there is cookies on the user PC and at the same time the Session is Not active so you should make session start and make user auto login again
    }

///There is no Cookies and Session is not alive
    elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && empty($_SESSION['user'])){
      // Here you can see that there is No cookies and at the same time the Session is Not active so you should take user to login page
    }
?>
```

Thats it and you need to arrange it with your own code but this is the method to done it !

**Note:** Make Sure on user Logout to clear cookies so it won't auto login again.

Comment: That means writing the session class from scratch and that's a hassle. CodeIgniters class gives me everything I need, plus I need the sessions to be stored in the database for remote disconnect and usage statistics.

Comment: No need to write it u can call the class Inside the IF 
i did give you the basic code to get started and this is a good method to begin with, BUT you need to modify it the way it fit your code

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, this config state finally helped:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 604800; // 604800 = 1 week
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 604800; // 604800 = 1 week
```

sess_time_to_update must be same as sess_expiration

sess_encrypt_cookie must be FALSE

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) under **How do Sessions work?**

> When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid
>   session data exists in the user's session cookie. If sessions data
>   does not exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created
>   and saved in the cookie. If a session does exist, its information will
>   be updated and the cookie will be updated. With each update, the
>   session_id will be regenerated.

Have you tried using the Code Igniter logging feature to see if the session module is purposely creating new sessions? More specifically, you probably want to do some debugging against the **CI_Session** class (*system/libraries/Session.php*).

There are 2 spots in `sess_read` where CI will determine there is no current session. If you enable logging, [per the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html), you can see if CI is hitting these conditions

### CI_Session::sess_read (condition 1)

```
// Fetch the cookie
$session = $this->CI->input->cookie($this->sess_cookie_name);

// No cookie?  Goodbye cruel world!...
if($session === FALSE)
{   
    log_message('debug', 'A session cookie was not found.');
    return FALSE;
}
```

### CI_Session::sess_read (condition 2)

```
// encryption was not used, so we need to check the md5 hash
$hash    = substr($session, strlen($session)-32); // get last 32 chars
$session = substr($session, 0, strlen($session)-32);

// Does the md5 hash match?  This is to prevent manipulation of session data in userspace
if ($hash !==  md5($session.$this->encryption_key))
{
    log_message('error', 'The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.');
    $this->sess_destroy();
    return FALSE;
}
```

I would guess at the first block, since you say the previously generated sessions are still hanging out in the database upon inspection. But definitely consider the logging feature and debugging the **CI_Session** class.

Comment: I've been logging and mt sessions all get destroyed on this condition:  // No result?  Kill it!
   if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
I cant put my finger on whats cousin this...

Comment: That's great, then you know where to look. Reading through the code it looks like there are no matching results in the database. Maybe you're calling `sess_destroy` somewhere else by hand? You might want to try expanding on the log messages to help determine the problem. I invited you to a chat if you want to try working through it a bit today.

Comment: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43705/code-igniter-session-problem) to chat. If anybody else on this thread wants in, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem running several applications under one CI installation. After several hours of line by line debug using xdebug, I found that each application in Codeigniter was having it's separate session. To resolve the error i provided separate name in each config.php file.

File one,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session1';
```

File two

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session2';
```

File Three

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session3';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use basic php code

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 32400);
```

Comment: and for Codeigniter i think you must to set both

Comment: This is incorrect. CodeIgniter's session system doesn't use PHP's native sessions at all.

Comment: While it is incorrect however, we can use native sessions with CI... :)